# Filter out already submitted forms?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath-data-connections

Using InfoPath 2010 in Web Forms, I can set a combobox to be populated from a SharePoint list. This part works fine.

Now what I want to do is exclude from the drop-down any matches in the form's submission list. Essentially these are account numbers and I don't want users attempting to submit the form for a given account more than once.

Google indicates that filters don't work on a web-form, and I can't seem to get a filter to work in the InfoPath filler anyways.

I'm trying to figure out if I can get the SharePoint lists like query-able data before it hits the form (so I can basically do `left outer join b where b is null`)

So far I haven't found any options like that. Any clues?

-**Edit**-
It seems almost like [Check if task has already been submitted on opening InfoPath task form and switching view to reflect so](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43199/check-if-task-has-already-been-submitted-on-opening-infopath-task-form-and-switc) but instead modifying a drop-down option set (to remove matches from the library).

Answer (score 0):

My current attempt uses a filter that gives the expression:

```
d:Account_x0020_Number != xdXDocument:GetDOM("Aud_Q1")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Account_x0020_Number
```

Where Aud_Q1 happens to be a data connection that retrieves the list of forms already submitted as a sharepoint list.

This was *actually working*, except for the fact that the form needed to be republished (instead of quick-published) because the original library's column was formatted like a number, which introduced commas into the list and therefore could no longer match.

It goes to show that you need to be consistent with your data types when trying to make comparisons.